# How to iterate through DevExpress items in RibbonPageGroup?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, devexpress, ribbon, ribbon-control

I need to iterate with a loop through all the items in a RibbonPageGroup. I try to set the Visibility property from all Ribbon Items to 'true/always'

```
    For Each rp As RibbonPage In ribbonControl.Pages
        rp.Visible = True
            For Each pg As RibbonPageGroup In rp.Groups
                    pg.Visible = True
                  For Each btn As DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItem In pg.??????
                      btn.Visibility = DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItemVisibility.Always
                Next
          Next
    Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no [bar items](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument1087) within the RibbonPageGroup. You can iterate [bar item links](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2514) via the [RibbonPageGroup.ItemLinks](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraBarsRibbonRibbonPageGroup_ItemLinkstopic) property.

Please refer to [Accessing Bar Items and Links](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument2515) article for more information.

Comment: Ok. Thanks i got it. Loop: For Each btn as Object In pg.ItemLinks

Comment: @NiklasB. I am happy to hear that my assistance was helpful to you. [You can accept the correct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using LINQ:

```
For Each bbi As var In RbpVersion.ItemLinks.Cast(Of BarItemLink)().[Select](Function(x) x.Item)
  Console.WriteLine(bbi.Caption)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Sorted it with this piece of coding. Works perfectly:

```
For Each pagegroup As DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonPage In rbnSafety.Pages
    For Each group As DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonPageGroup In pagegroup.Groups
        For Each button As DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItem In group.Ribbon.Items.OfType(Of DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItem)()
        If button.Name <> "rbtnExit" Then
           button.Enabled = False
        End If
        Next
        For Each button As DevExpress.XtraBars.BarSubItem In group.Ribbon.Items.OfType(Of DevExpress.XtraBars.BarSubItem)()
            button.Enabled = False
        Next
     Next
 Next
```